# Query column 6 has type STRING which cannot be inserted into column start_station_id, which has type INT64 at [2:1]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working on data analysis using BigQuery. I have 12 CSV files for 12 months that need to be put together into one table.

I did that using `INSERT INTO` which worked well for some months but I got the error

> Query column 6 has type STRING which cannot be inserted into column start_station_id, which has type INT64 at [2:1]

for some months.

The dataset is called "Dataset", the table I have put the data together is called `Main`, and the table I can't `INSERT INTO Main` is `Dec2020`

I have tried to change datatype in Dec2020 to int64 using the query below. It says the query has run successfully but when I try to INSERT INTO again, it gives me the same error: Query column 6 has type STRING which cannot be inserted into column start_station_id, which has type INT64 at [2:1]

Query:

```
WITH SELECT CAST (start_station_id AS int64) AS start_station_id
FROM `Dataset.Dec2020`,
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO `Dataset.Main`
SELECT * 
FROM `Dataset.Dec2020`
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: I would suggest you look at fixing the load rather than trying to retro fix data that you dont actually know was loaded correctly

Answer (score 0):

a couple of suggestions

1. Never use *, always explicitly list your columns in both the INSERT and SELECT statements so that you know which source column is being written to which target column. It also ensure that if additional columns are ever added to the source/target it won't break your code
2. Put the CAST in your SELECT statement - I'm not sure what you're doing with that WITH statement but as it is unconnected to the subsequent INSERT it is going to have no effect